# Modification of a gekko intermediate at a particular timestep

Tags: simulation, gekko

Can I either
a) use an if statement in an intermediate to modify the equation at a particular timestep or
b) solve the model for t = 0 to t1, redefine the intermediate, solve the model for t = t1 to tend or
c) something else?

Read the gekko documentation. Hoping to use gekko to simulate an induction motor connected to a power system.

Comment: I think I got it. I put the entire model inside a loop including m=gekko() and it runs. I should be able to modify the model using match/case statements.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by defining a switch variable:

```py
s = m.Param([0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0])
r = m.Intermediate(s*3 + (1-s)*5)
```

This gives a value of `3` when `s=1` and a value of `5` when `s=0`. This strategy is used to define time-based or event-driven conditions that have a switching behavior.

It is also possible to use `m.if3(condition,0,1)` to create the switch if there is a condition that determines the switch. This creates an additional binary variable at every time step so the solution speed may decrease.